# How to let the Graph fill the screen?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

In this scenario, Graph instance's width and height must be `number`, so can't use `100%` as value:
https://codesandbox.io/s/mo-ban-wchooy?file=/src/App.tsx

```
const graph = new Graph({
      container: containerRef.current!,
      width: 600,
      height: 800,
      background: {
        color: "#F2F7FA"
      }
    });
```

so how to let the graph fill the parent div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just write the code like this:

```js
const graph = new Graph({
  width: document.body.clientWidth,
  height: document.body.clientHeight,
});
```